# How can I download pdf generated by Tcpdf from my android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, pdf-generation, tcpdf, androidpdfviewer

Need a help to solve my problem.
In my android webview a pdf which is generated using **tcpdf** is not working properly ...
It generates some garbage values in the pdf

//download file
myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
@Override
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

```
            DownloadManager.Request myRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            myRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            myRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            //new

            myRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");


            //create download manager
            DownloadManager myManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

            myManager.enqueue(myRequest);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Downloding file....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    //TCPDF

    myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            //start download
            DownloadPDF downlooadPDF = new DownloadPDF();
            downlooadPDF.execute(url, userAgent, contentDisposition);

            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Downloding ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}


//TCPDF

private class DownloadPDF extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);

            File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/myPDF");

            // create the directory if it does not exist
            if (!myDir.exists()) myDir.mkdirs();

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();

            //get filename from the contentDisposition
            String filename = null;
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(sUrl[2]);
            while (m.find()) {
                filename = m.group(1);
            }

            File outputFile = new File(myDir, filename);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            connection.disconnect();
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

            displayPdf(); // a function to open the PDF file automatically

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void displayPdf() {
        try {

            Object filename = fileList();
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/myPDF/" + filename);




            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("TAG", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Hello, Can you show off the current work you have done and which result you got?

Comment: sorry for the delay .... i just add the download portion of my work above ....